# Why am I not Able to Construct This Regex

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, runtime-error, construct

I wrote this regex:

```
(.+?)\s*{?\s*(.+?;)\s*}?\s*
```

Which tests fine: https://regex101.com/r/gD2eN7/1

But when I try to construct it in C++ I get a runtime-error.

> Unhandled exception at 0x7714C52F in temp2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception:
>   std::regex_error at memory location 0x003BF2EC.

```
const auto input = "if (KnR)\n\tfoo();\nif (spaces) {\n    foo();\n}\nif (allman)\n{\n\tfoo();\n}\nif (horstmann)\n{\tfoo();\n}\nif (pico)\n{\tfoo(); }\nif (whitesmiths)\n\t{\n\tfoo();\n\t}"s;

cout << input << endl;

cout << regex_replace(input, regex("(.+?)\\s*{?\\s*(.+?;)\\s*}?\\s*"), "$1 {\n\t$2\n}\n") << endl;
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/ke3R7P)

Am I using functionality that C++ doesn't support?

Comment: Consider using a "raw string literal" for your regex - that will save you from "escaping stuff hell" and make your code more readable. Also, please include code, errors and the like directly in the question rather than just providing links - links go stale and disapear and also introduce an extra barrier (more work) for your patient (free) reviewers. Don't make us work harder than we have to.

Comment: C++ Shell does not give any errors (http://cpp.sh/7bue).

Comment: Escape the curly braces: `regex_replace(input, regex("(.+?)\\s*\\{?\\s*(.+?;)\\s*\\}?\\s*"), "$1 {\n\t$2\n}\n")` - http://ideone.com/jlH6QS

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That sir would make an excellent answer.

Comment: Probably worth typing the text of the error message and not just sticking a picture of it in. (I know it's odd that Microsoft still doesn't let you select the text; perhaps they think their own help is so great nobody needs to actually ever search the net for more information.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the curly braces. See the [`std::regex` ECMAScript flavor reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/):

> `\character`
>   The character *character* as it is, without interpreting its special meaning within a regex expression.
>   Any *character* can be escaped except those which form any of the special character sequences above.
>   
> **Needed for: `^` `$` `\` `.` `*` `+` `?` `(` `)` `[` `]` `{` `}` `|`**

```
regex_replace(input, regex("(.+?)\\s*\\{?\\s*(.+?;)\\s*\\}?\\s*"), "$1 {\n\t$2\n}\n")
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/jlH6QS)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const auto input = "if (KnR)\n\tfoo();\nif (spaces) {\n    foo();\n}\nif (allman)\n{\n\tfoo();\n}\nif (horstmann)\n{\tfoo();\n}\nif (pico)\n{\tfoo(); }\nif (whitesmiths)\n\t{\n\tfoo();\n\t}"s;

    cout << regex_replace(input, regex("(.+?)\\s*\\{?\\s*(.+?;)\\s*\\}?\\s*"), "$1 {\n\t$2\n}\n") << endl;
    //                                           ^^                ^^
}
```

Comment: Any insight as to why not escaping caused the runtime error?

Comment: I cannot debug right now, but it must be something related to the way ECMAScript is implemented in `std::regex`. In JavaScript, there would be no issue since the JS regex engine "knows" the `{` and `}` that do not enclose a number are no limiting quantifier. Here, I believe this guessing mechanism is flawed. Actually, one can't debug a regex in JavaScript and be sure it will work with `std::regex` ECMAScript pattern.

Comment: Yet another bug in C++'s very specification. Nice.